# Is "robots.txt" necessarily needed?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, robots.txt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need robots.txt?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20068/do-i-need-robots-txt)

From my understanding robots.txt is only needed to do something different from the norm like exclude a certain file directory and such, but if this is true why do so many people think it is important on every website? Should I just put it on every website to be sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have anything that you wan't to tell the searchengines you don't wan't indexed (or crawled) don't. It doesn't impact your indexing.

See [this question](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) answered by Google.